# Unable to cut and paste in Android Studio(mac)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I know this has been asked before I have read all the ones I can find with out much help.  I am unable to cut and past inside Android studio.  I have just moved to a Mac and have not had an issue before with a windows machine.  Things I have tried are as follows.  Check to make sure my short cuts are correct. invalidate caches/restart.  Also added ide.mac.useNativeClipboard=True to bin/idea.properties.  Aswel as using the mouse to try to cut and paste.  Any other idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Update I can cut and paste code just fine.  The issue is only cutting and pasting layers and objects in the layers them selfs(ImageButtons,Buttons etc)

Answer (score 0):

I used `File | Settings | Editor` and under Limits Change value of maximum number of contents to keep in clipboard to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is only with Android 2.2.1  I installed 2.1 and the issue went away.